# IE9 restore down, divs not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am using IE9 on windows 7.

I have a web site where the problem described below works consistently in latest versions of FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari...

In IE9 however, when I restore down the browser, or, resize it, there are is a table on one of the pates whose td's contain some divs that do not resize to adjust to the container (div).  If I refresh the page, it renders properly.  Does anyone know of anything specifically in IE9 that would cause this, and if so, is there a fix (css or js)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a DOCTYPE for your markup?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
```